# stm32f103 usb failed with "No open pipes!"

Tags: usb, stm32

I am trying connect my stm32f103c8 board to PC with several examples from internet, but all of them face the same issue, they can not be installed successfully.

By using "usbview.exe" from windows, I get this error

```
              ---===>Device Information<===---
English product name: "YunfeiVirtual COM Port  "

ConnectionStatus:                  
Current Config Value:              0x00  -> Device Bus Speed: Full
Device Address:                    0x03
Open Pipes:                           0
*!*ERROR:  No open pipes!
```

while a normal usb device may have following:

```
          ---===>Device Information<===---
English product name: "USB-Serial Controller"

ConnectionStatus:                  
Current Config Value:              0x01  -> Device Bus Speed: Full
Device Address:                    0x04
Open Pipes:                           3
```

But if I install usb driver manually, my device is still able to use. Following is my full log for your reference:

```
[Port1] 


          ---===>Device Information<===---
English product name: "YunfeiVirtual COM Port  "

ConnectionStatus:                  
Current Config Value:              0x00  -> Device Bus Speed: Full
Device Address:                    0x03
Open Pipes:                           0
*!*ERROR:  No open pipes!

          ===>Device Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x12
bDescriptorType:                   0x01
bcdUSB:                          0x0200
bDeviceClass:                      0x02  -> This is a Communication Device
bDeviceSubClass:                   0x00
bDeviceProtocol:                   0x00
bMaxPacketSize0:                   0x40 = (64) Bytes
idVendor:                        0x0483 = STMicroelectronics
idProduct:                       0x5711
bcdDevice:                       0x0200
iManufacturer:                     0x01
     English (United States)  "Yunfeielectronics"
iProduct:                          0x02
     English (United States)  "YunfeiVirtual COM Port  "
iSerialNumber:                     0x03
     English (United States)  "8D7232A25049"
bNumConfigurations:                0x01

          ===>Configuration Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x09
bDescriptorType:                   0x02
wTotalLength:                    0x0043  -> Validated
bNumInterfaces:                    0x02
bConfigurationValue:               0x01
iConfiguration:                    0x00
bmAttributes:                      0xE0  -> Self Powered
  -> Remote Wakeup
MaxPower:                          0x32 = 100 mA

          ===>Interface Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x09
bDescriptorType:                   0x04
bInterfaceNumber:                  0x00
bAlternateSetting:                 0x00
bNumEndpoints:                     0x01
bInterfaceClass:                   0x02  -> This is Communications (CDC Control) USB Device Interface Class
bInterfaceSubClass:                0x02
bInterfaceProtocol:                0x01
iInterface:                        0x00
  -> This is a Communications (CDC Control) USB Device Interface Class

          ===>Descriptor Hex Dump<===
bLength:                           0x05
bDescriptorType:                   0x24
05 24 00 10 01 
  -> This is a Communications (CDC Control) USB Device Interface Class

          ===>Descriptor Hex Dump<===
bLength:                           0x05
bDescriptorType:                   0x24
05 24 01 00 01 
  -> This is a Communications (CDC Control) USB Device Interface Class

          ===>Descriptor Hex Dump<===
bLength:                           0x04
bDescriptorType:                   0x24
04 24 02 02 
  -> This is a Communications (CDC Control) USB Device Interface Class

          ===>Descriptor Hex Dump<===
bLength:                           0x05
bDescriptorType:                   0x24
05 24 06 00 01 

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x82  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 2
bmAttributes:                      0x03  -> Interrupt Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0008 = 0x08 bytes
bInterval:                         0xFF

          ===>Interface Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x09
bDescriptorType:                   0x04
bInterfaceNumber:                  0x01
bAlternateSetting:                 0x00
bNumEndpoints:                     0x02
bInterfaceClass:                   0x0A  -> This is a CDC Data USB Device Interface Class
bInterfaceSubClass:                0x00
bInterfaceProtocol:                0x00
iInterface:                        0x00

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x03  -> Direction: OUT - EndpointID: 3
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0040 = 0x40 bytes
bInterval:                         0x00

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x81  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 1
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0040 = 0x40 bytes
bInterval:                         0x00
```